# is there a way to convert a single row to a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hi all I have been trying to convert this DataFrame

```
col_1  col_2  col_3
item1  item2  item3
 $1xx   $2xx   $3xx
```

to this output:

```
col_1   NaN   col_2   NaN  col_3  NaN
item1  $1xx  item2   $2xx  item3  $3xx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can avoid duplicated and also `NaN`s columns, so here is alternative with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), flatten `MultiIndex Series` anf create one row DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with trnspose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
s = df.unstack()
s.index = s.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = s.to_frame().T
print (df)
  col_1_0 col_1_1 col_2_0 col_2_1 col_3_0 col_3_1
0   item1    $1xx   item2    $2xx   item3    $3xx
```

Another solution with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
df = df.reset_index().melt('index', value_name=0)
df.index = df['variable'] + '_' + df['index'].astype(str)

df = df[[0]].T
print (df)
  col_1_0 col_1_1 col_2_0 col_2_1 col_3_0 col_3_1
0   item1    $1xx   item2    $2xx   item3    $3xx
```